# Create row from 3 arrays with PHP

Tags: php

I hope someone can help me with this:

From my form I receive the following post:

```
Dump => array(3) {
["category_id"] => array(14) {
[0] => string(1) "1"
[1] => string(1) "1"
[2] => string(1) "6"
[3] => string(1) "6"
[4] => string(1) "2"
[5] => string(1) "2"
[6] => string(1) "4"
}
["stock_id"] => array(14) {
[0] => string(1) "0"
[1] => string(1) "1"
[2] => string(1) "0"
[3] => string(1) "1"
[4] => string(1) "0"
[5] => string(1) "1"
[6] => string(1) "0"
}
["del_times_id"] => array(14) {
[0] => string(1) "1"
[1] => string(1) "2"
[2] => string(1) "1"
[3] => string(1) "1"
[4] => string(1) "1"
[5] => string(1) "1"
[6] => string(1) "1"
}
}
```

I want to combine these arrays like this (if possible):

(1,0,1),(1,1,2),(6,0,1),(6,1,1),....etc.

Comment: your title says "create row" - but what exactly? a string, an array. Post the desired final output

Answer (score 1):

The solution using `array_map` and `implode` functions:

```
$arr = [
"category_id" => ["1",   "1",   "6",   "6",   "2",   "2",   "4"],
"stock_id" => ["0",   "1",   "0",   "1",   "0",   "1",   "0"],
"del_times_id" => ["1",   "2",   "1",   "1",   "1",   "1",  "1"]
];

$mapped = implode(',', array_map(function($v){
    return '(' . implode(',', $v) . ')';
}, array_map(null, $arr["category_id"], $arr["stock_id"], $arr["del_times_id"])));

print_r($mapped);
```

The output:

```
(1,0,1),(1,1,2),(6,0,1),(6,1,1),(2,0,1),(2,1,1),(4,0,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `category_id`, `stock_id` and `del_times_id` always contain the same number of items: Simply iterate over your items, collect one of every subitem and push it into your resulting array.

```
$result = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($data['category_id']); $i++) {
    $result[] = [
        $data['category_id'][$i],
        $data['stock_id'][$i],
        $data['del_times_id'][$i],
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array(
"category_id" => array("1",   "1",   "6",   "6",   "2",   "2",   "4"),
"stock_id" => array("0",   "1",   "0",   "1",   "0",   "1",   "0"),
"del_times_id" => array("1",   "2",   "1",   "1",   "1",   "1",  "1")
);  
  foreach($arr as $value){

        foreach($value as $k=>$v){      
          $data[$k][] = $v;     
        }    

    }

    print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ cat test.php 
<?php
$arr = [
"category_id" => ["1",   "1",   "6",   "6",   "2",   "2",   "4"],
"stock_id" => ["0",   "1",   "0",   "1",   "0",   "1",   "0"],
"del_times_id" => ["1",   "2",   "1",   "1",   "1",   "1",  "1"]
];


print_r(
    implode(',',
     array_map(
        function($a,$b,$c){ 
           return sprintf('(%s,%s,%s)',$a,$b,$c);
        }, 
        $arr["category_id"], 
        $arr["stock_id"], 
        $arr["del_times_id"]
        )
     )
 );

?>
```

Output

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ php test.php 
(1,0,1),(1,1,2),(6,0,1),(6,1,1),(2,0,1),(2,1,1),(4,0,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$output = '';
foreach ($p['category_id'] as $k => $v) {
$output .= '(' . $v . ',' . $p['stock_id'][$k] . ',' .$p['del_times_id'][$k] . '),';
}
$output = substr($output, 0, -1);
?>
```